# How to save as pdf from JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, jasper-reports

I am exporting to JSP page using jasperexportmanager as below.

```
jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(statReportSummaryJasper, param,jre);
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = res.getOutputStream();
res.setContentType("application/PDF");
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);

servletOutputStream.flush();
servletOutputStream.close();
```

This gets rendered in JSP page. When I try to download, It gives me option to save as html and not as PDF. How do I save this as PDF.

Any help or direction will be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: is this a pdf document? or is it html? that is why you only have the option to save it as html

Comment: Hi Eugene, Its rendered as a html page as you said. But I get all the option which are available when we open a PDF document in the browser. Like zoomin zoom out, download option...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Nagarajan....

add this code and try once again...

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
            + ReportName + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas, Thanks for the reply. On adding the code the PDF file gets downloaded. But If I want to display it as pdf in browser tab itself without downloading, how do I go about it.

Comment: Hi All/Srinivas, to display it in the browser without saving I just changed the code as below
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
            + ReportName + ".pdf");
And it opened the PDF in the browser and the user can save the PDF if he wants. Thank you all again. Objective: Accomplised

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the code as below response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + ReportName + ".pdf"); And it opened the PDF in the browser and the user can save the PDF if he wants. Thank you all again. Objective: Accomplised

Answer (score -1):

This is a "non-programmers" answer!
Our bank generates statements in jsp which I wanted to save as pdfs (in order to email them to a person even less technical than I am). In the end, I just opened the downloaded jsp in my browser (Chrome) and printed it to a pdf.  That was satisfactory for me.

Comment: Makes sure to answer the question or provide a viable alternative

Comment: Thanks, Hugo, but, although my answer was unrelated to jasperexportmanager, his question seemed to be how to save his jsp output as a pdf and I didn't see the difference between saving his output and saving my bank's jsp output. I still stand to be corrected, though!